# Change open dropdown list position based on scroll position within the page

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css

Having the following Blazor component DropdownMenu I'm trying to implement a way to open the `<ul>` element upwards or downwards based on where the dropdown component position is located.

Here is the DropdownMenu.razor component:

```
@typeparam T

<div @ref="_dropdownMenuContainer" class="group flex relative">
    @if (ButtonTemplate != null)
    {
        @ButtonTemplate
    }
    <ul role="listbox" class="w-56 group-focus-within:block hidden z-30 absolute min-h-[2.8rem] text-left max-h-56 overflow-x-auto rounded-lg bg-white text-base shadow focus:outline-none right-0 @GetDropdownPosition() @DropdownMenuListClass">
        @if (Items == null)
        {
            @LoadingTemplate
        }
        else
        {
            if (EmptyTemplate != null && !Items.Any())
            {
                @EmptyTemplate
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in Items)
                {
                    <li role="option" class="group/list-item">
                        @if (ItemTemplate != null)
                        {
                            @ItemTemplate(item)
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            }
            @if (FooterTemplate != null)
            {
                <div class="flex flex-row justify-between p-4 text-xs text-gray-700">
                    @FooterTemplate
                </div>
            }
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the code behind DropdownMenu:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace IdFund.Common.Components.TopBar;

public partial class DropdownMenu<T>
{
    private ElementReference? _dropdownMenuContainer;
    private bool _shouldOpenUpwards;
    
    [Parameter] public string? DropdownMenuListClass { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ButtonTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<T>? Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<T>? ItemTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? EmptyTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? LoadingTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? FooterTemplate { get; set; }
    
    [Inject] public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; } = null!;
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        IJSObjectReference module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
            "./_content/IdFund.Common.Components/TopBar/DropdownMenu.razor.js");
        
        if (firstRender && _dropdownMenuContainer is not null)
        {
            _shouldOpenUpwards = await module.InvokeAsync<bool>("shouldOpenUpwards", _dropdownMenuContainer);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private string GetDropdownPosition()
    {;
        return _shouldOpenUpwards ? "bottom-14" : "top-14";
    }
}
```

And this is the JavaScript function I implemented:

```
export function shouldOpenUpwards(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const bottomSpace = viewportHeight - rect.bottom;
    const topSpace = rect.top;
    
    const dropdownHeight = 88;

    return bottomSpace < topSpace && topSpace > dropdownHeight;
}
```

Is there a way to improve this implementation to track scroll position of the user and while dropdown menu is open to switch it's position to up or down depending on how far the component is from the edges of the browser window?